# What is a Tab Control?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, tabs, panel

In the most basic sense, what is a Tab Control?

---

I am looking into creating one from scratch (I have many good reasons for this and simply extending existing ones won't make me feel better). But I am not sure how they are made.

Is a Tab Control just a bunch of Panels, inside a main Panel? Here's a picture of what I mean...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At it's core, TabControl is a *very* simple control.  Nothing but a row of rectangles with text on them.  It is Winforms that adds the TabPage class, a scrollable container control that adds the ability to hide controls.  Derived from the Panel class.

It bulks up with features that you can arbitrarily drop.  Like rendering in a way that's compatible with the active visual styles theme that the user selected.  And dealing with an app that asks for more tabs than can fit in a row.  And implementing both keyboard and mouse navigation.  And implementing transparency so the parent window content is visible behind the tabs.

It is so simple that the need to implement your own is rare :)